# For a typescript project, which one is better: TSLint or ESLint?

Tags: typescript, eslint, tslint

A Typescript file can be linted by both TSLint and ESLint. I want to know which one is better. In other words, I want to know if they have the same features for linting Typescript files? How they differ e.g. from the performance point of view?

Comment: What research have you done on the subject? If you can provide more details on your own research and list them out, people can help you elaborate. This kind of question is hard for people to answer because they don't know what aspects you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [TypeScript Roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29288#developer-productivity-tools-and-integration) due to some architectural problems of TSLint, ESLint is better. ESLint is more performant. Also, that community has more interest in ESLint. Regarding these, the TypeScript team has decided to focus on ESLint. However, there are features like program-wide linting and semantic linting that are not currently supported in ESLint. If one wants to use such features, they need to use TSLint.

Comment: Hi, that is not quite accurate - all features of TSLint are now available in ESLint.